# How do I convert a signed decimal value to a 32 bit little-endian binary string?

Tags: java, binary

I need to convert a signed decimal number into a 32 bit little-endian binary value. Does anyone by any chance know of a built-in Java class or function that can do this? Or have built one to do this?

The data is a longtitude/latitude value like -78.3829. Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you want to make the conversion? Round? Convert to a 32-bit decimal and pretend it's an integer? Some other format?

Comment: like this: `round(-78.3829*100000)`, and then convert to 32 bit little endian binary.

Comment: So what's the problem you're having with that? Seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps at all, here's a class that I made that converts longs to binary Strings and binary Strings to longs:

```
public class toBinary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(decimalToBinary(16317));
        System.out.println(binaryToDecimal("11111111111111111111111111111111111100101001"));
    }

    public static long binaryToDecimal(String bin) {
        long result = 0;
        int len = bin.length();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            result += Integer.parseInt(bin.charAt(i) +  "") * Math.pow(2, len - i - 1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String decimalToBinary(long num) {
        String result = "";
        while(true) {
            result += num % 2;
            if(num < 2)
                break;
            num = num / 2;
        }
        for(int i = result.length(); i < 32; i++)
            result += "0";
        result = reverse(result);
        result = toLittleEndian(result);
        return result;
    }

    public static String toLittleEndian(String str) {
        String result = "";
        result += str.substring(24);
        result += str.substring(16, 24);
        result += str.substring(8, 16);
        result += str.substring(0, 8);
        return result;
    }

    public static String reverse(String str) {
        String result = "";
        for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            result += str.charAt(i);
        return result;
    }

}
```

It doesn't take decimal values, but it could probably give you a bit of guidance.

Comment: does the decimalToBinary return a little endian value or big endian value?  I need a little endian value.  If it returns a big endian value, would returning the result without running the reverse function return it as little endian?

Comment: I just edited it to make it return a little endian value.  Returning the result without the reverse function would not, however, return it as a little endian value (with what I had before) since endian-ness goes by the byte, not by the bit.

Comment: Thanks. I have always had trouble with binary.  The values I am converting are longitude and latitude coordinates.  The latitute values are always positive, but the longitude values are always negative, bc it is within a limited geographical area.  You code only returns a single 0 for the longitude values.  The `num < 2` is causing it to `break` out of the loop after one iteration.  I don't mean to be a bother, but you wouldn't by chance know how to convert a negative `long` number to binary, would you?

Comment: To convert a negative `long` to binary, all you would have to do is convert the absolute value of the number to binary, switch all the 1's to 0's and the 0's to 1's, and then add one to the result and you've got yourself a negative binary number.  I don't have time to code that right now (I'm at work), but really the only challenging part would be implementing the addition of 1.  I feel like I've given you enough to go by to figure this out on your own.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  I will work out the code for myself. Like I said I have always had trouble with binary.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, binary isn't the easiest thing to work with.  Glad I could help!

Comment: Jack, quick question if you don't mind.  I need the binary number to be 32 bits.  so for the negative number, I took the absolute value, converted to binary (which gave me a 22 bit binary string), ran the reverse function so it was in the proper order, then I left padded the appropriate amount of zeros to make it 32 bits.  Then I did the bit switch like you said and added 1.  My question is whether I should do the bit switch then left pad the zeros or if I should pad the zeros first like I am doing currently?

Comment: If I understand your question, you should add the zeros to the *positive* binary string, THEN flip the bits, THEN add 1.  Make sense?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I am doing.  I just wanted to make sure that was correct.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is trivial once you know what the endianess means on binary level. The question is more what do you really want to do with it?

```
public static int flipEndianess(int i) {
    return (i >>> 24)          | // shift byte 3 to byte 0
           ((i >> 8) & 0xFF00) | // shift byte 2 to byte 1
           (i << 24)           | // shift byte 0 to byte 3
           ((i & 0xFF00) << 8);  // shift byte 1 to byte 2
}
```

This little method will swap around the bytes in an int to switch between little/big endian order (the conversion is symetric). Now you have a little endian int. But what would you do with that in Java?

More likely you need to write the data to a stream or something, then its only a question in which order you write the bytes out:

```
// write int to stream so bytes are little endian in the stream
// OutputStream out = ... 
out.write(i);
out.write(i >> 8);
out.write(i >> 16);
out.write(i >> 24);
```

(For big endian you would just order the lines from bottom to top...)